# the role of hebrew accents in Ps.27:13

Tags: hebrew

why are there so many accents around this word 'lule לוּלֵא' in Ps27:13? And how do these change the meaning or feeling of the word?

Comment: It's probably to tell how to sing the word, rather than changing the meaning.  You probably need a Rabbi to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

The verse in the Leningrad is pointed this way:  ”ל֗וּלֵ֗֗א֗“ (Psalm 27:13 HMT-W4)

The shureq and sere are the normal pointings we might expect.  But there are, as you note, dots above the words.  These are the so-called "Puncta Extraordinaria." It is generally assumed that the points are there to call our attention to the scribal uncertainty of the word. Tov writes:

> d. Extraordinary Points (Puncta Extraordinaria)
>
> In fifteen places,63 ð” indicates dots above letters or words and in
> one place (Ps 27:13) also below them.64 Although these dots originally
> denoted the erasure of letters → p. 203, traditionally they were
> explained as indications of doubtful letters. → Butin* and Ginsburg*,
> quoting rabbinic sources.65 Ten of these instances are found in the
> Torah, four in the Prophets, and one in the Hagiographa.
>
> (Emmanuel Tov, Textual Criticism of the Hebrew Bible, 3rd ed.
> (Minneapolis: Fortress Press, 2012), 51-52.)

Why might that word have been in question?  לוּלֵא introduces and unreal condition:

> —1. if not; unless (unreal condition !): with pf. לוּלֵא הָיָה if …
> had not been Gn 3142 4310, cj. Nu 2233, Ju 1418 1S 2534 2S 227 Is 19
> Ps 10623
>
> (HALOT, s.v. “לוּלֵא,” 2:524.)

That understanding goes against David's flow of thought. So, the thought is that through *aposiopesis*, instead, it's an affirmation instead of an unreal condition.  Again HALOT gives this as the gloss:

> —2. affirmation surely (< 1, through aposiopesis of the rest of the
> clause in final position, Gunkel) Ps 2713 (punctuation for deletion,
> Ginsberg 333f; Geiger 258; Bauer-L. Heb. 79s, but indispensable). †
>
> (HALOT, s.v. “לוּלֵא,” 2:524.)